# Hide API key in Get Request

Tags: reactjs, security, azure-functions

I have set up a secured Azure Function with AD authentication to be consume in the React app.

This involves sending the following GET request with the an API key as the parameter.

```
https://{domain_name}.azurewebsites.net/api/PowerBiEembeddedToken?code={my_api_key}
```

However, I think this is unsafe given I can see the API key in the Network XHR tab of the browser.

[image]

1. Is this ok from a security perspective?
2. If not, is there a canonical way of handling this or hide the API key?

Comment: You have setup using `AD authentication` then why are you sending the key? what is the `AuthorizationLevel` setup at your function? If you are not using Easy Auth then pass the token and validate at Function level.

Comment: Passing the `x-functions-key` either by query parameter or request header from browser to server can be a security thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer from the documentation.

The key can be included in a query string variable named code, as above. It can also be included in an `x-functions-key` HTTP header. The value of the key can be any function key defined for the function, or any host key.